# Route to index in controller

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

I would like to route back to index ('/') in my controllers. How would I do this, I tried the following:

```
public function randomAction()
{
  return $this->redirect()->toRoute('/');
}
```

But with this I get the following error:

> Route with name "" not found

Any ideas why this is happening, and how I can properly route back to index? I could use `/application`, but I don't want that to appear in the address bar. Is my only option in this case `toUrl('/')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example on [the skeleton application](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php#L13), try the route **home**

```
public function randomAction()
{
  return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home');
}
```

### [ZF2 Docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#the-redirect-plugin)

*toRoute($route, array $params = array(), array $options = array()): Redirects to a named route, using the provided $params and $options to assembled the URL.*

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the name of the route to `toRoute`, not the actual route.

If you are using the ZF Skeleton Application then the "index" route is called `home` so you'd do the following:

`return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home');`

If not open your module config and find the `routes` array. The name of the route is the key in this array that points to your route configuration.